# named pipe error while registering new SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, and trying to create new Server for standalone use I am getting following error

> TITLE: New Server Registration
>
> Testing the registered server failed. Verify the server name, login credentials, and database, and then click Test again
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: Are you certain you also installed the database engine and not just SSMS? Are there any entries in SQL Server Configuration Manager?  Also, have you tried to run Repair on the instance from the SQL Server Installation Server?

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?